# boto3 upload_file, how to pass aws keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-3.8

I'm currently using the upload_file function from this [boto3 upload_file doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html)
to upload an CSV to an S3 bucket from an AWS parallel cluster (?) instance.

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):
    """Upload a file to an S3 bucket

    :param file_name: File to upload
    :param bucket: Bucket to upload to
    :param object_name: S3 object name. If not specified then file_name is used
    :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
    """

    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_name

    # Upload the file
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True
```

On that documenation url, it also lists an ExtraArgs parameter

> s3.upload_file(
> 'FILE_NAME', 'BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME',
> ExtraArgs={'Metadata': {'mykey': 'myvalue'}}
> )

Here's my attempt/understanding:
So, I'm trying to add my aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key to the ExtraArgs, but is this the right way to do it?

```
upload_file(year_month + ".csv", "bucket", "object_name" + year_month + ".csv", ExtraArgs={'Metadata': {'aws_access_key_id': 'X', 'aws_secret_access_key': 'Y'}})
```

Because this doesn't work:

```
upload_file(year_month + ".csv", "bucket", "object_name" + year_month + ".csv")
```

Thanks

Comment: No metadata is for including things like Content-Type. See [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html) for how boto3 gets its credentials

Comment: @jordanm thanks for the link! so, I can add the aws keys to to this line?  
`s3_client = boto3.client('s3')`

Comment: You can, but that's not recommended. Best way is to use either environment variables or set them in a config file using the command `aws configure`

Comment: What's an "AWS parallel cluster (?) instance"? If your compute instance is running in AWS, you provide it credentials through an IAM role.

Answer (score 1):

As other users suggested the best aproach is configure your access keys in enviroment variables or roles (if is a resource inside AWS, like Lambda, EC2 instance, etc.), but if you go for bad practices or simplily are working on premise application, the way of include these data as variables inside your code is

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_zone, aws_access_key_id=key_id, aws_secret_access_key=access_key)
```